# Changing system time causes application to hang LINUX (LUBUNTU) TCL/TK

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, time, tcl

I have a tcl/tk with c desktop application, and one of the requirements is to change the system time, in the background there are threads running from the c code, and "after" commands from the tcl code. Whenever I change the time to an earlier time the system hangs 
i.e: `05:50:12` -> `05:45:12` also i get weird behavior when going forward in time. I'm running lubuntu. I'm not sure what to do in this situation, I made some test and it seems the after keeps on waiting after i change back in time.

to change the time i use : `exec date --set="STRING"` from the tcl code

Comment: Read [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) and learn about [adjtime(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/adjtime.3.html), [NTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol), [chrony](http://linux.about.com/cs/linux101/g/chrony.htm)...

Comment: If you really, really know what you are doing, you can build a custom Tcl with overriden time functions (see http://www.tcl.tk/cgi-bin/tct/tip/233.html) and get total control. Just moving the system time back and forth is a pretty heavy handed tool. So yes, of course you get weird behaviour when you let your system pretend to be time travelling.

Answer (score 1):

Tcl depends on the system time (converted to seconds from the start of the Unix epoch) increasing fairly close to monotonically for the correct behaviour of a number of things, but most particularly anything in the `after` command. Internally, `after` computes the *absolute* time that an event should happen and only triggers things once that time is reached, so that things being triggered early (which can happen because of various OS events) don't cause problems. If you set the system time back a long way, Tcl will wait until the absolute time is reached anyway, which will look a lot like a hang.

Just synch your clock with NTP (i.e., switch on `ntpd`) and stop fiddling with the system clock by hand.

Comment: the problem with ntp that it has to be connected to the internet this application won't be connected to the internet.

Comment: Can you give a reason for fiddling with the system time? Why is this needed at all?